# Rails tutorial Chapter 10.1.4: "User has already been taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am going through Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and getting spec validation errors in Chapter 10.1.4 even though I think I'm following the instructions.

I'm a Rails newbie but it looks like Factory Girl is trying to create a User that already exists, even though the following code is supposed to create a new micropost and assign it to an existing user:

FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)

Does anyone know how to fix the errors?

**Errors**

1) User micropost associations should have the right microposts in the right order
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User has already been taken
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:159

2) User micropost associations should destroy associated microposts
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User has already been taken
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:159

**user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

    before do 
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
        password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") 
    end

    subject { @user }

    it { should respond_to(:name) }
    it { should respond_to(:email) }
    it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
    it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
  it { should respond_to(:admin) }
    it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
    it { should respond_to(:microposts) }

    it { should be_valid }
    it { should_not be_admin }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                         foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
          addresses.each do |invalid_address|
            @user.email = invalid_address
            @user.should_not be_valid
        end      
      end
  end

  describe "when email is not downcase" do
    let(:uppercase_email) { "TEST@TEST.COM"}

    it "should be set to downcase" do
        @user.email = uppercase_email
        @user.save
        @user.email.should == uppercase_email.downcase
    end 
  end

    describe "when email format is valid" do
        it "should be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
          @user.email = valid_address
          @user.should be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

    describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email.email.upcase!
        user_with_same_email.save
      end

      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

    describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

    describe "return value of authenticate method" do
      before { @user.save }
        let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
        it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
        let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

        it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
        specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
        end     
    end

    describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
    end

    describe "remember token" do
    before { @user.save }
    its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
  end

    describe "with admin attribute set to 'true'" do
      before do
      @user.save!
        @user.toggle!(:admin)
      end

      it { should be_admin }
    end

    describe "confirm admin attribute is not accessible" do
        it "should not be accessible" do
            expect do
              @user.update_attributes(:admin => true)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end  
  end 

  describe "micropost associations" do

    before { @user.save }
    let!(:older_micropost) do 
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
    end

    let!(:newer_micropost) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
    end

    it "should have the right microposts in the right order" do
      @user.microposts.should == [newer_micropost, older_micropost]
    end

    it "should destroy associated microposts" do
      microposts = @user.microposts.dup
      @user.destroy
      microposts.should_not be_empty
      microposts.each do |micropost|
        Micropost.find_by_id(micropost.id).should be_nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # Rails::logger.info "hello"

    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }   
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

  factory :micropost do
    content "Lorem ipsum"
    user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same error #2  you describe below.  I found that by restarting `spork` and re-running rake `db:test:prepare` that the error was resolved.

Comment: This one fixed it for me. One of those maddening errors because it's not the code your looking at that's the problem. The tutorial mentions a few times the need to restart spork, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using FactoryGirl to create a user object there. Near the top of your **user_spec.rb**, the assignment to @user that starts `@user = User.new...` should instead be this:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

That way a new object with a unique email address will be created before every test.

Comment: Hey, I tried that but unfortunately I am still getting the same errors. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried resetting your test database? rake db:test:prepare